# How to build mc for kubuntu without root access?

Tags: linux, kubuntu, build, midnight-commander

mc (Midnight Commander) in Kubuntu 9.10 (Karmic Koala) has a [problem](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mc/+bug/397505) accessing `.zip` and other archives as a virtual file system. It has to do with a changed format of the output from `unzip`. Discussions offer a workaround, but that requires system (i.e. `root`) file access; my work box is locked down.

I have Ubuntu (without the K) 9.10 at home, and I downloaded the source package and made a code change that's a horrible hack (I would not dream of publishing) that would allow me to run my own correctly working copy of `mc` in a subdirectory of my `$HOME`. Alas, my "at home" box is configured differently, both in terms of processor(s) and KDE vs. Gnome; a transferred-over mc executable fails immediately with `bus error`.

Question, then:

Given

- an Ubuntu box I completely control,
- non-root on a KUbuntu box that has `make` and `gcc` and some other tools but not a complete development toolchain, such as the stuff underneath `config`
- ability to download any packages I need
- ability to create and muck around in my own $HOME tree

how can I build an `mc` that will run on my locked-down Kubuntu box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `mc` gets built with [autotools](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/), you can configure the package in such a way that it does not install into a system, but a user directory which is writable by you. You do this by giving extra options to the `./configure` call you issue. To see all available build options run

```
./configure --help
```

The magic bullet here is the `PREFIX` variable used: it (roughly) tells the build process where all your programs and support files get installed. This can be fine-tuned further.

When I build and install as user, I usually install into a `PREFIX` in `$HOME/bin/progname.dir`, while the executables go directly into `$HOME/bin`, so for your case

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/bin/mc.dir --bindir=$HOME/bin
```

and then

```
make install
```

In your `.profile` file you should update your `$PATH` variable to include `$HOME/bin/` by adding a line like

```
export PATH=$HOME/bin:PATH
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give that a try tomorrow.

I'm a little worried about `GLIB`. There are some GLIB 2.0 `.so`'s on my system, but nowhere a `glib-config`.

Comment: Drat! I'm still having problems. `configure` calls `chk-config` and that looks for GLIB. It wants a `glib-config` and can't find one. I made a separate question of that: http://superuser.com/questions/115671/where-to-get-glib-config-for-kubuntu

Comment: OK, I got it working. See my answer for details. Still, you got me well started, so here's my check mark for you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Success!** This is feedback for anyone else with similar problems.

As [honk](https://superuser.com/users/21992/honk) helpfully explained, `configure` can be helped along with some options. I found this wasn't quite enough, though: I had to manually change the links from `./config/` to `config.sub`, `config.guess`, `install-sh` and `missing`.

After that, I had lots of problems getting `configure` to find my `glib 2.0`. It turns out that `configure` calls `chk-config` and that has a number of different ways to find `glib`, none of which worked. I looked manually for the stuff it was trying to find and discovered that `glib-2.0.pc` was indeed available. I could make `chk-config` find it by pointing `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to the directory containing all those `.pc` files.

I wrote a tiny shell script to provide `configure` with all the required environment variables and options. Here it is:

```
#!/bin/bash
my_root=/home/carl/MC
export PKG_CONFIG=$my_root/usr/bin/pkg-config
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$my_root/usr/lib/pkgconfig
OPTS=""
OPTS="$OPTS --disable-glibtest"
OPTS="$OPTS --enable-extcharset"
OPTS="$OPTS --enable-netcode"
OPTS="$OPTS --enable-charset"
# OPTS="$OPTS --with-glib-static"
# OPTS="$OPTS --with-glib-12=no"
./configure --prefix=$my_root $OPTS
```