# Where to get glib-config for Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, build, glib, compile

I'm trying to compile Midnight Commander on a KUbuntu 9.10 (Karmic) box **with no root access.** I've set up a directory under `$HOME`, downloaded the `mc` source package and various stuff required for building, such as `autotools`. I've unpacked the `CONTENTS` of all those packages into this working directory such that I have the usual `./usr`, `./lib`, `./etc` hierarchy. I manage to get `configure` through a lot of tests, but I can't seem to fool it into finding `glib`.

```
checking for glib-2.0... checking for glib-config... no
checking for glib12-config... no
checking for glib-config... no
checking for GLIB - version >= 1.2.6... no
*** The glib-config script installed by GLIB could not be found
*** If GLIB was installed in PREFIX, make sure PREFIX/bin is in
*** your path, or set the GLIB_CONFIG environment variable to the
*** full path to glib-config.
configure: error: Test for glib failed.
GNU Midnight Commander requires glib 1.2.6 or above.
```

My system has `glib` installed:

```
/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.3
```

... and I've also downloaded and unpacked the glib package into my working directory:

```
libglib2.0-0_2.22.2-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
libglib2.0-dev_2.22.2-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
```

... but still the elusive `glib-config` is nowhere to be found. It's not in any debian package for Karmic, either.

So I'd appreciate any help getting over this hurdle. Please note, again, that I don't have root, so I can't just merrily `apt-get` stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem myself, but I'm embarrassed to admit I don't remember exactly how. Here's an approximation:

For my second attempt, I created a complete "build filesystem" under my home directory and copied into this the `content` portions of all dependencies (including glib2). With that, and correct use of the flags on `configure`, and the inclusion of a couple of include directories in the `CFLAGS` environment variable, I managed to get `configure` to complete without error. A bit of fiddling later, `Make` fell into place as well. Thanks to having my own directory tree for all my utilities and the results of building, I was even able to `make install`.

Of course the resulting program was dependent on the support of that home-built directory tree.

Answer (score 0):

You mayu be out of luck. You need libglib 1, and you have libglib2. I see that while old version (version 1) existed in ubuntu 9.04, they've removed it from 9.10.